# mysql query to display output based on two data

Tags: mysql

in my table the structure is like that

TableA

```
first_column        second_column       third_column
wwwew                   frfrffee          rfffrfr
dddfdd                  fffrfrfr          rfddwdrv
etc
```

if users has not set the value of second_column i want to display the result of first_column but if users has specified the value of second_column i want to display the second_column value.

i tried where clause with 'and' & 'or' statement but it is not working.

second_column is child of first column so if users has set parent only then the output will be based on parent but if users has set parent as well as child or only child the output will be based on child input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can accomplish what you're trying to do using the [`coalesce()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function.

```
select coalesce(second_column, first_column) from TableA;
```

Comment: i have a join statement so i am using where clause to choose the data can you please tell how i can do with where clause as query is very complicated and any changes will not give the proper output

Comment: Please post your very complicated query.